# Are objects a variable type or a name given to variables inside a class?

Tags: c#, oop, variables

I've got a very basic understanding of OOP but I am a little confused as to what constitutes an object so sorry if this sounds like a stupid question.

```
public class StatMetaData
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string categoryKey { get; set; }
    public string categoryName { get; set; }
    public bool isReversed { get; set; }
}
```

In my code i'm using this class to store parsed JSON information and I understand how it all works but was wondering if because these variables are part of their own class do these count as objects? Or does it have to have the `object` data type to be classed as an object?

If I'm totally off on my understanding any help would be much appreciated, websites I've looked at don't give a very good definition of what actually can be classed as an object.

Comment: `do these count as objects`, yes, they are all objects; including the class itself.

Comment: Give this a read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/common-type-system

Comment: Your confusion is very common and I have edited books written by people who should know better who got it wrong. Lots of web sites get it wrong too. It's a good idea to ask the question, so don't worry about sounding stupid! The important thing to understand is that *variables are not objects. Variables are storage for values.* There are three kinds of values in C#: references, values of value type, and pointers. You will not likely ever need to use pointers.

Comment: I note also that in your sample code those are not variables, those are automatically-implemented properties. The compiler generates a variable for you behind the scenes, called the backing field. Again, the backing field is not an object. It is storage that contains either a reference to a string, in the case of `string` properties, or a Boolean value, in the case of `bool` properties.

Comment: All that said, I note that when speaking informally it is very common to say "this variable is an object that..." when we mean "this variable refers to an object that..." Because variables allow you to smoothly and easily dereference references, it is very easy to get into the bad habit of confusing the storage of a reference with the thing itself. It's like in real life if you wrote down "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue" on a piece of paper, pointed to it, and said "that's where the President lives" we would not confuse the paper or the writing with the house!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c# ***almost*** **everything** is an object, let's take your code for example:

```
public class StatMetaData
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string categoryKey { get; set; }
    public string categoryName { get; set; }
    public bool isReversed { get; set; }
}
```

all the items below are true:

```
object c = new StatMetaData(); //thus the instance of the class is an object
object k = new StatMetaData().Key; //an instance of string is also an object
object b = new StatMetaData().isReversed; //an instance of bool is also an object
```

In simple terms (and it goes beyond this simple statement) let's say an object is `basically anything that you store in memory`. When you declare a class of type `StatMetaData` you don't have an object because there's no instance, you're just declaring the `Type`... only when you create a new instance of `StatMetaData` you have an object in memory.

Also note that, for example `object myObj;` isn't an object in memory until you have something like `object myObj = new object();` the object type is also that, a type.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. What is the object data type used for then?

Comment: Well... everything starts somewhere, `object` is just a base class where the c# developers put code that is generic to all types, like the `GetType()` method for example

Comment: I would disagree with calling `bool`s and instances of other value types objects. While the language syntax may be the same, they are compiled differently.Your third assignment has a hidden boxing conversion; the assignment itself creates the object.

Comment: @ILMTitan check the conversation in [RagnaRock answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60532151/5762332) . Value types are also objects in C#, even when not boxed.

Answer (score 4):

In C#, an object is a structured chunk of memory in the heap. The structure is defined by the class the object is an instance of. Instances of the classes `object`, `string` and your `StatMeataData` are all objects.

Variables, fields and properties are not themselves objects, but can store a reference to one.

Comment: I would just change the word "structure" as it can generate confusion with "structs"

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

A "class definition" is what an object made from that class will look like.  It specifies *properties* (such as `key` and `name`) that others can use, and *methods* that others can call.  In addition, it can define "private" things that only the object will see.  It is, if you will, a *recipe* for creating an actual object.

An "object," then, is a concrete instantiation of a particular class:  memory has been allocated, initialization has been completed, and now you have a bouncing baby "instance."

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
Just found out now and in C# everything is an object, in Java for instance value types are not considered Objects

> All value types implicitly inherit from the class System.ValueType,
>   which, in turn, inherits from class object.

I think your question should be what is a **value type** and what is a **reference type** and where are they stored.

You can read about value types [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types).

Basically Value types are:

- Structures
- Enums
- Integral numeric types
- Floating-point numeric types
- bool that represents a Boolean value
- char that represents a Unicode UTF-16 character

Value types are typically stored in the stack and reference types in the heap.
But if value types are part of a reference type, they will be stored with their reference type.

Comment: I disagree with 75% of this post; sorry 99%. `All of those are not objects, everything else is an object.` what? `The reason they are not objects is because they don't have any methods or properties`, miss-leading and wrong, `object` most certainly does have methods.

Comment: Why? I think value types to be considered objects, need to be "boxed"

Comment: Where do you think `Enum` derives from, `object`. `Boxing` and `Unboxing` is a different topic TBH.

Comment: "All value types implicitly inherit from the class System.ValueType, which, in turn, inherits from class object."

But is this enough to consider them "Objects"? what is not an object then?

Comment: Nothing, everything in some form or fashion derives from `object`. IMHO, the OP sounds confused, I honestly believe they want to know the difference, I am assuming though.

Comment: Seems to be true in C# indeed, Not in Java, wich is also OOP, where these value type are not considered Objects, they are primitive types

Comment: Correct, Java they are not, `c#` they are :)

Comment: Also, structs do have methods and properties.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ `C#’s unified type system effectively means that value types can become objects "on demand."` doesn't that makes us think that value types are not usually objects, only when boxing?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: A few minor corrections: Enum derives from ValueType which derives from Object. Pointers are neither objects nor variables; pointers are non-object values which point to variables. An interesting question is whether an interface type is *derived* from object; interfaces are *convertible* to object, but the only thing that can *implement* an interface is an object.

Comment: @Magnetron: The spec does not say "value type can become objects on demand". The spec says, on page one, "All C# types, including primitive types such as int and double, inherit from a single root object type."  I note that the spec is wrong here because pointer types do not inherit from object and there is some debate as to whether it makes sense to say that interface types inherit from object, but it is certainly the case that only objects can implement an interface, so we'll give that a pass.

Comment: Yes, I know from ValueType, but then object, should have worded it different, thanks!

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you! Then, [this MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables) from which I quoted should be modified.

Comment: @Magnetron: OMG that is terrible. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I'll have a word with the documentation manager.

Comment: I've left a sternly worded comment for Bill, who will surely add it to his long list of corrections. :) Again, thanks for bringing this to my attention. There is an immense amount of C# documentation and I was unable to review all of it for accuracy when I was at Microsoft, and they've only made more since I left.